# Unable to dispatch redux action after receiving firebase DB data

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, redux

I'm using react native app to get data from firebase database. The idea is to dispatch an action to initialise `store.appState` as soon as data is received from FirebaseDB. The issue is that dispatch is not fired when data is received. What am I missing?

I'm using redux-thunk middleware.

// database.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

const config = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "..."
}

const Database = firebase
  .initializeApp(config)
  .database()
  .ref()

export default Database
```

// actions.js

```
import database from 'database'

const setInitDataFromFirebase = data => {
  return ({
    type: SET_DATA_INIT,
    payload: {
      data
    }
  })
}

export const loadAction = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    Database.once('value', snapshot=>{
      console.log(snapshot.val()) // i get the log with correct data
      dispatch(setInitDataFromFirebase(snapshot.val())) // this is not dispatched
    })
  }
}
```

// container.js

```
const View = (appState, loadData) => {
     if (!appState) loadData() // appState is null initially
}

const matStateToProps (...) // passes appState
const mapDispatchToProps (...) // passes loadData

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(View)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this figured out. Turns out I made a very basic typo when I was importing redux-thunk. I should have done

```
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
const store = createStore(
  RootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk, logger)
)
```

What I had wrongly done was

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
const store = createStore(
  RootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
)
```

Comment: the capitalisation wouldn't make a difference, your error was probably actually something else

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You're right. I'd used 'thunk' at the time. I'll update the answer.